# Custom upload for a generated form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a generated form which I can't add HTML directly to it.
This form has 2 upload boxes which needs to have a custom styling. I have managed to style the upload box, but upon testing the function which I need to be triggerd, doesn't trigger.

To clarify, here is my code and what I tried:

The html (that is autom being generated):

```
<div class="controls">       
   <input class="span3" type="file" name="img1" id="img1" />
</div>
```

This is the jQuery

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=file]', function() {
    var input = $(this),
        numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
        label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
    input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
});


$(document).ready(function() {    
    var fileinput = $('input[type=file]', this);
    var file_parent =  fileinput.parent(); // get the parent
    var fileinputhtml = file_parent.html(); // the HTML of the parent (which is input)

    file_parent.replaceWith('<span class="btn btn-file"><span class="btn-class btn-primary">Browse</span>'+fileinputhtml+'<span class="form-control"></span></span>');

    // The upload function has been triggerd
    fileinput.on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {

        console.log(label); // When the .replaceWith() is active, it doesn't show this log.

        var input = $(this).parent().find('.fileupload-filename');

        console.log(input.val(label));

        if( input.length ) {
          input.val( label );
        }

    });
});
```

Maybe it has an easy solution but I really can't seem to get this to work.
You help would be highly appericiated

Comment: The fileselect event doesn't exist, what exactly are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I found this handy tutorial [http://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3/] where this event is used. It is works more like a trigger

Comment: Is it on purpose that there is two buttons ?
Because on the tutorial you gave me, the html is not dynamically generated.
Until i don't know exactly what you're trying to do I can't help you.